# Incrementing a counter when a button is clicked (JavaScript, HTML)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want  to display a button for an HTML document, and each time this button is clicked it increments. 
After incrementation I want that number(which is the counter to be saved) for when the file is accessed again the counter shows for the users. 
What I read is that there is a function called addBtn, which on click increments how is it possible to save the incremented value

```
    addBtn.on("click", function() {
    counter.html(++value);
    return;          
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That would be something like this. Just replace the "your_textfield" with your selector.

```
  var counter = 1;
  function increase(){
      var textBox = document.getElementById("your_textfield");
      textBox.value = counter;
      counter ++;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 addBtn.on("click", function() {
   var counter=$(this).html();
   counter+=1;
   $(this).html(counter);
   return;          
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with a file you need a php to do it for you

but this one is a simple one using localstorage of web browers

you can check the console log of your browser

where in its shows a object storage

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .overlay {
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%
        }
    </style>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <p class="display"></p>
    <input type="button" class="add" value="click me">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('ready', function(){
            var count = 0;
            var storage = window.localStorage;
            var disp = $('p.display');
            if (storage.getItem('count')) {
                count = parseInt(storage.getItem('count'));
                disp.html(count);
            }

            $('.add').on('click', function(){   
                if (storage.getItem('count') != null) {
                    count = parseInt(storage.getItem('count'));
                }
                count++;
                storage.setItem('count', count);
                disp.html(count);
                console.log(storage);                

            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the counting value doesn't show though, how is it possible to call and print the counting value right next to it?

Comment: can we consider it as a string and write in document.write()?

Comment: you can check the console log of your browser

Comment: check the new code again if you want the display to apper